# trouble searching by first / last name combinations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I'm having problems searching by first / last / first + last name combinations.

I had it working correctly with first names & last names, but with first+last name combinations it was also listing all of the OTHER members with the same last name. Does the `StartsWith` method not work the way I'm thinking it does or is there some sort of logical error here?

I tried this way:

```
predicate = predicate.And(p => query.StartsWith(p.FirstNm) && query.EndsWith(p.LastNm) || query.StartsWith(p.FirstNm));
```

I also tried this way:

```
predicate = predicate.And(p => query.StartsWith(p.FirstNm) || query.StartsWith(p.LastNm));
```

With these names:

> ```
> John Doe
> Jane Doe
> Cody Phillips
> Cody Fisher
> ```

Typing in `Cody` yields both `Cody` results. Typing in `Cody Fisher` yields the correct result.

Typing in `John Doe` yields both `John Doe` and `Jane Doe`. I only want it to yield `John Doe`.

Comment: Can you show us the generated T-SQL that was sent to SQL server? ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386961.aspx )

Comment: Isn’t `query.StartsWith(p.FirstNm) && query.EndsWith(p.LastNm) || query.StartsWith(p.FirstNm)` equivalent to just `query.StartsWith(p.FirstNm)`? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Douglas I think so. The first name last name conjunction won't change the results. If you did that first and gave higher priority to those results, then if that didn't return anything did just first name that would make sense.

Comment: @Douglas, updated the post with what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be of some help. I believe you're misusing the StartsWith method. From what I gather you should instead be using the Like method.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/128fe4cf-776d-4200-9f48-7f8dd30dcb34/